# Missing Reference and weird error in Cosmos (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cosmos

I am trying to create an "OS" using Cosmos and C# in Visual Studio but on running it gives me an error box saying that there are errors in this build and if I would like to run the last build, but since there is no last build, I get another error, which is not of my concern. The error box gives me another 22 code related errors. The code is generated by Cosmos and is a basic code example and it should run on the first try. The errors tell about missing references for Cosmos and basic C# libraries like `System`.

[Check out the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dubgB.png)

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Include errors as text (not images) inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had to restore the NuGet packages and install some additional Cosmos packages. :)